# Why char *x not char x?

Tags: c++

I've a code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(char *name){ // ???
    cout << "String: " << name << endl;
}

int main(){
    foo("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I use "char name" won't work. Please help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string can be represented as an array of char(s). You can use the char * pointer to refer to that string.
You could use `char name` with `foo('c')`, because that's a char.

Comment: "c" is still a string. 'c' would be a char (but only in C++; in C it would have type int).

Comment: I didn't do it to mantain Nick and Bastien Léonard comments consistent.

Answer (score 3):

`char a` is just a *single* character, while `char*` is a pointer to a sequence of characters - a string.

When you call `foo("Hello")`, you pass in a string literal (strictly speaking an array of `char`s) which is convertible to a pointer to `char`. Therefore `foo` must accept `char*` rather than `char` because otherwise the types wouldn't match.

Answer (score 2):

`char name` is a single character

`char* name` is a pointer to a character in heap and if allocated correctly, can be an array of characters.

Comment: Aye but I stated it there for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

char refers to a single character.  char* is a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) to an address in memory that contains a 1 or more characters (a string).  If you are using C++, you might consider using `std::string` instead as it may be slightly more familiar.

Comment: that *more than likely* contains a sequence of characters.  `char *c = new char;` is valid, AFAIK.

Comment: Fun part is, even `new char[0]` works in gcc (though it throws a warning).  I'm not familiar enough with the standard to know whether this works everywhere, but it's also documented at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr199.htm and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

Because a simple `char` is just one character, like `'c','A','0',etc.`. `char*` is a pointer to a region in memory, where one or more `char`s are stored.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ strings are quite often represented as an array of characters terminated by the null character.

Arrays in C and C++ are often represented as a pointer to the first item.

Therefore a string is represented as a pointer to the first character in the string and that is what `char *name` means. It means `name` is a pointer to the first character in the string.

You might want to read up a bit on pointers, arrays and strings in C/C++ as this is fundamental stuff!